# DDD : can I start from UI designs to design my domain?

Tags: dns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm new to Domain Driven Design, and I'm reading a lot about it. I started a first implementation of what I consider to respect DDD principles.

But now, I'm wondering something : to define the sub domains and contexts, I started from well defined UI designs. They describe well every steps that take when you want to interact with the app.

Do you think it is a good start point (of course, I also got close from the domain experts) ? I mean, UI's define the Use Cases no ?

**An example :**

You have an administration panel, and from this panel, you can manage companies. So, I conclued that my sub-domain is `Administration/` and one of its context is `Company/`.

So I end up with something like this :

```
src/
   Administration/
       Company/
           Domain/
           Command/
           Ports
```

Is it poor designed Domain ?

I'd really like to have your opinions about this please.

Have a nice day.

------- edit ------

As @Luca Masera said, My example was a little bit too tiny.

So to give more example, I would have ended up with something like :

```
src/
    Administration/
        Company/
            Domain/
                Company.model
                Employees.collection
            Commands/
                AddEmployeeToCompany.command
                GetAllEmployeesForACompany.query
            [...]
        Employees/
            Domain/
            Commands/
            [...]
    FrontEnd/       <--- didn't really think about the naming yet
        Contracts/
            Domain/
                Contract.model
                CompanyId.id
                Employee.model
            Commands/
                ChangeContractForEmployee.command
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't really understand, because you've made only a single sample, if you end up splitting the same domain on each ui area. What I know is that the ui defines the use cases, but how they are implemented should not define the design of the domain.

If you have an Administration and, for example, a Frontend, and you split the Company domain between the two, then the answer is no, it's not ok. The Company domain should have all its logic enclosed in a single package, not scattered around several context.

For example, in my last application I've to manage the user Absences. There're several types of them: holidays, maladies, exemptions and some others. I've also another concept, the Prospects: they cone from a sub-system and give general information for each type of Absence.

When the users starts the application, the first entry point is in the Prospects domain. The ui loads the page and then, with the help of Javascript and Ajax it asks a section of the page to each other domain. Every further interaction with the domain is managed by the ui (implemented in the infrastructure layer) of that domain.

--- After the editing ---

I would not do something like this. As I wrote before, in this way you end up splitting the domain logic in each macro area. Hence you loose all the advantages of the DDD.

I elaborate a bit more: what would you do when, later, in the *Administration* you need something about the *Contracts*?

Whatever architecture you use, you'll have:

```
src/ 
    contracts/
              infrastructure/
                             *** My way to manage the UI interactions ***
                             ui/
                                frontendA/ (it could be *hr_team*)
                                frontendB/ (it could be *managers*)
                                frontendC/ (it could be *employers)
              application/
              domain/
    companies/
              infrastructure/
                             *** My way to manage the UI interactions ***
                             ui/
                                frontendA/ (it could be *hr_team*)
                                frontendB/ (it could be *managers*)
                                *** no employers actions are planned *** 
              application/
              domain/
```

Into the *infrastructure* you'll implement the Controllers that allow to interact with the Domain using the code inside the *application* layer. There're some overlapping here and there with the roles (some employers could be managers, some other part of the hr_team) but not with the functionalities.

In this way you still keep the logic of the domain (contracts) all together, but you end up with a nice splitting of the functionalities for each role.

Comment: Yes you guessed right, my intent was to do split my domains by UI area. I edited my previous post to give you more matter to judge.